# Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Full error : `Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.`

My code in index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
export default root;
);
```

My code in app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import MyHome from "./components/MyHome";
import About from "./components/About";
import root from "./index";

function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <div>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <MyHome></MyHome>
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      element: (
        <div>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <About></About>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ]);

  root.render(<RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>);
}

export default App;
```

I was trying to setup my react router but got this error. I looked through the documentation of react router dom but thats pretty confusing and couldnt find my solution

Answer (score 1):

`root.render` should only be called once.  You call it once in App, and once in index. It should really only be called in index.js. App should be a standalone component which does not attempt to re-render the root element.  The startup docs for react-router are pretty useful to get started using it:

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First you have used  `root.render()` twice, use it only in index.js
Secondly you have defined your routes in index.js and then tried to create nested routes.
**You dont need to write your code like this**

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

instead you should have done it like this

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>)
```

And then define your routes in the App.js as you did.

Comment: Thanks for the help the error is resolved

Comment: Wait i just realised that when I replaced `root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>)` to `
  <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>` nothing renders in my app 
and my index.js looks like ``` const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
 ```

Comment: i think you are  doing something wrong in App.js file. 
Please refer to the official documentation for more information [link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)